# How can I iterate over each element in an array through for each?

Tags: java

I'm trying to iterate each element of array A. I'm failing to do it, though with pre-fixed array elements this works.

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Number of elements in array B = ");
        int y = scanner.nextInt();

        int B[] = new int[y];

        System.out.println("Enter the elements of array B : ");
        for (int i : B) {
            i = scanner.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Elements of array B : ");
        for (int i : B) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm failing to do it, though with pre-fixed array elements this works. - what do you mean by this ?

Comment: `public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] A = {2, 4, 6, 8};
        int[] B = {22, 44, 64, 88};

        System.out.println("Elements of array A :");
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(A[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("Elements of array B :");
        for (int i : B) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }

    }

}`

Comment: You're confusing the element with the indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Number of elements in array B = ");
int y = scanner.nextInt();

int B[] = new int[y];

System.out.println("Enter the elements of array B : ");
for (int i = 0 ; i < y ; i++ ) {
    B[i]= scanner.nextInt();
}
```

In above loop you can not use for each for insert. When you write `for (int i: B)` it means for every element i in B array, and
your B is empty. So use traditional loop to insert and for each to fetch element from array.

```
System.out.println("Elements of array B : ");
for (int index : B) {
    System.out.println(index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just edit your first `for` loop as below and it will work

```
for (int i =0; i<y; i++) 
{
    B[i] = scanner.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if using a for each loop would work when entering in each element of the array.
You're on the right track, so a regular for loop would serve you better :)